# How can I run all tests that are inside a folder in Protractor without adding it as a suite to the config file

Tags: protractor, automated-tests

Hi does anyone know how you can either make a folder executable in Protractor or create a separate folder/module to run all the tests that are inside a folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protractor protractor.conf.js --specs='specs/*.js'
```

The above cmd will execute all the files in `specs` folder.

--spec is used to specify where your test files are residing.